# Different versions in manifest on different machines

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, build

Have two machines, both with VS2005 SP1 installed and with the WinSXS showing the same things installed.

When one machine builds a particular C++ .dll .vcproj it ends up with

```
<assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.MFC' version='8.0.50727.762' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
```

in its manifest file. But on the other machine it ends up with

```
<assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.MFC' version='8.0.50608.0 processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
```

even though this machine does not have '8.0.50608.0' libraries listed in its WinSXS.

The .dll built on this machine with the older version referenced has some problems. I have ensured both machines have the same latest source code and references etc..

What could be causing it to build with the different reference?

Thanks!

Terry

Comment: Have you verified both IDE and OS are having same updates/service-pack ?

Answer (score 1):

The machine with "8.0.50608.0" does not apparently have VS 2005 SP1 installed. Possibly you are confused by VS About Box that tells something about '.NET SP1' that has nothing to do with the issue.